# findstr() Runtime error 23 when called as a subprocess?

Tags: vb6

I am attempting to run `findstr` command from within my vb6 project however it seems that I am in over my head in determining the correct syntax.

I was calling a batch file to run the `findstr` but trying to integrate it in the project is failing.

```
'''''''' Lines below allow ONLY Numeric text in teh Test1 box
Dim textval As String
Dim numval As String

Private Sub Text1_Change()
  textval = Text1.Text
  If IsNumeric(textval) Then
    numval = textval
  Else
    Text1.Text = CStr(numval)
  End If
End Sub
'''''''' Lines above allow ONLY Numeric text in teh Test1 box


Private Sub Command1_Click()
''''Lines below enables program/project to execute in the current `enter code here`directory
Dim MyCurrentDir As String
'Show current directory
MyCurrentDir = CurDir
'  MsgBox "Current Directory is " & MyCurrentDir
''''Lines above enables program/project to execute in the current directory

' Remarked for testing below WORKS: Shell (MyCurrentDir & "\findstring.bat " & Text1)
' TEST BELOW

Dim command As String
'findstr "%1" *achineCont*.log | findstr  "Q_OUTFEED_EJECTBAG_SIG">FOUNDBAG.txt
command = "findstr "" & Text1 & "" *achineCont*.log | findstr  ""Q_OUTFEED_EJECTBAG_SIG"">FOUNDBAG.txt"
Shell "cmd.exe /c command"

'findstr "Done" *ai*.log | findstr  "writing" | findstr "%1">>FOUNDBAG.txt
Command2 = "Done"" *ai*.log | findstr  ""writing"" | findstr "" & Text1 & "">>FOUNDBAG.txt"
Shell "cmd.exe /c command2"

'start "" cmd /c cscript ReadTimeFromFileWriteToNewFile.vbs
Command3 = "start """" cmd /c cscript ReadNewFile.vbs"
Shell "cmd.exe /c command3"
' TEST ABOVE
End Sub



Private Sub Command2_Click()
Unload Form1        'tell the form to unload
Set Form1 = Nothing 'free the memory used by the variables
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()

''''Lines below enables program/project to execute in the current directory
Dim MyCurrentDir As String

'Show current directory
MyCurrentDir = CurDir
'  MsgBox "Current Directory is " & MyCurrentDir
''''Lines above enables program/project to execute in the current directory
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You are several quotes away from being correct in each command.  You need to triple up some of the quotes, and re-position some of the others.  For the first command, try this:

```
Command = "findstr """ & Text1 & """ *achineCont*.log | findstr  ""Q_OUTFEED_EJECTBAG_SIG"">FOUNDBAG.txt"
```

For the second command, try this:

```
Command2 = """Done"" *ai*.log | findstr  ""writing"" | findstr """ & Text1 & """>>FOUNDBAG.txt"
```

And last but not least, for the fourth command, try this:

```
Command4 = "findstr ""Done"" *ai*.log | findstr  ""writing"" | findstr """ & Text1 & """>>FOUNDBAG.txt"
```

A good way to figure these out is to display the string with either Debug.Print or a MsgBox and adjust quotes until the string is correct.  Also, remember a string has opening and closing quotes.  Any other quotes within the string need to be escaped by doubling up the quote.

Comment: Thanks Brian.  would you by any chance have some input for this line ? Command2 = "findstr """Done""" *ai*.log | findstr  """writing""" | findstr """ & Text1 & "">>FOUNDBAG.txt"